# Color range for multiple lines

Tags: d3.js, colors

I'm diving into d3 but be still an absolute beginner so bear with me if this is an obvious one.

I have a line graph with multiple lines (actually about ~150) which I would like to color in a range between lets say red to blue.

I managed to hard code the color of the lines with something like

```
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal() 
  .range(["#FF0000",  "#0000FF"]);
```

but I obviously don't want to do that for 150 different color values. Is there a straight forward way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify how you're going to choose each line. I'm assuming it's by their indices, not by any bound datum. That being the case, a simple linear scale...

```
const scale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 149])
    .range(["#FF0000",  "#0000FF"]);
```

...can work, to which you'll pass the indices.

Here is a demo:

```js
const scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 149])
  .range(["#FF0000", "#0000FF"]);

d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(150))
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", (_, i) => scale(i))
```

```css
div {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

However, if you do want to use an ordinal scale, for any reason, you don't need to manually create each colour in the range. You can use a D3 interpolator to create the array, like this:

```
const interpolator = d3.interpolateRgb("#FF0000", "#0000FF");
const colors = d3.range(150).map(t => interpolator(t / 149));
```

Then, you just need to pass that array to your ordinal scale's range:

```
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal() 
    .range(colors);
```

Here is the demo:

```js
const interpolator = d3.interpolateRgb("#FF0000", "#0000FF");
const colors = d3.range(150).map(t => interpolator(t / 149));

console.log(colors)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you and you are right it's done by indices. I used scaleOrdinal as it was the first one I came across